Problem in my optimization model (JuMP/Julia/Gurobi) where one variable refuses to go above 0
I am currently writing an Optimization Model which is meant to give advice to companies about the integration of a decentral energy system (it's for my bachelor's thesis, so nothing very complex). A company is represented by load profiles for heat and electricity for every hour of 1 year. The model will then decide how the company will satisfy the energy needs. The companies can either buy the energy (electricity and heat) off the grid or produce it themselves. If they produce it themselves, they need to pay the investment costs for the technologies and the operational costs each year.
The objective is to minimize the annualized costs of the companies.
The electrical energy can be produced by PV-Panels and windwheels, taken from hydrogen storage (an electrolyzer produces hydrogen from electricity, stores it in a tank as hydrogen, and reconverts it back to energy by a fuel cell when needed), or produced from heat by an ORC (basically a technology that can convert heat into electricity). Heat can be produced by the electrolyzer and fuel cell (in this example an SOFC). The heat is transferred by heat-exchangers to be used to satisfy the need for heat from the thermal load profile.
My problem is the following: The model refuses to purchase heat from the grid (electricity works fine). Even if I put a negative price (like FWP = -10 or -1000000) it refuses to buy heat. When I set the heatexchanger efficiency (Phi_heatex) to 0, the only option for the model should be to buy energy from the grid. But it doesn't. It will crash with 0 solutions found.
I have been searching for a logical error for a whole day now and can't seem to find it. ChatGPT/Copilot neither. Does someone else see a mistake here? I would be very thankful if someone could have a look here. The code will be below. The variable for heat purchased in a period is H_purchased[p].
function model_szenario_SOFC_51(enterprise_index , thermal_loadprofile_index) #Szenario 1 beinhaltet die PEM-FC
    u = load_profile_20[enterprise_index] #in u wird gespeichert welches Unternehmen gerade betrachtet wird. Der Index dieses Modells in der Liste wird bei Funktionsaufruf übergeben
    t = t_lp[thermal_loadprofile_index]
    #Build Model
    m = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer)

    #Electricity
    @variable(m, Total_Demand >= 0 ) #Total demand of electrical energy over all periods p [kWh_therm]
    @variable(m, Total_H_Demand >= 0) #Total Demand of thermal energy over all periods [kWh_therm]
    @variable(m, Total_PV_gen >= 0) #Total PV-Generation over all periods p [kWh]
    @variable(m, Total_Wind_gen >= 0) #Total Wind-Generation over all periods p [kWh]
    @variable(m, Total_FC_gen >=0) #Total Fuel-Cell Output over all periods p [kWh]
    @variable(m, Total_cycle_gen >=0) #Total ORC Output over all periods p [kWh]
    @variable(m, Total_heat_gen >=0) #Total Heat produces over all periods p [kWh]
    @variable(m, Total_H2_gen >=0) #Total Electrolyzer Output over all periods p [kWh]
    @variable(m, Total_buy >= 0) #Total electrical energy purchased over all periods p [kWh]
    @variable(m, Total_sell >= 0) #Total electrical energy sold over all periods p [kWh]
    @variable(m, Total_H_buy >= 0) #Total thermal energy bought over all periods p [kWh]
    @variable(m, E_sold[1:P] >= 0) # electricalenergy sold in period p [kWh]
    @variable(m, E_purchased[1:P] >= 0) # electrical energy purchased in period p [kWh]
    @variable(m, H_purchased[1:P] >= 0) #thermal energy purchased in period p [kWh]
    @variable(m, max_E_purchased >= 0) #highest amount of energy purchased in any period [kWh]
    @variable(m, EC) #Total energy cost over all periods [€]

    #Technology
    @variable(m, cap_PV >= 0) #Installed PV capacity [kWh]
    @variable(m, cap_Wind >= 0) #Installed Wind capacity [kWh]
    @variable(m, cap_EL >= 0) #Installed Electrolyzer capacity [kWh]
    @variable(m, EL_bin, Bin) #needed to make sure FC isnt used without EL
    @variable(m, cap_SOFC >= 0) #Installed Fuell Cell capacity [kWh]
    @variable(m, cap_H2T >= 0) #Installed Hydrogen-tank capacity [kWh] 
    @variable(m, cap_Heatex_EL >= 0) #Installed EL-Heatexchanger capacity [kWh]
    @variable(m, cap_Heatex_SOFC >= 0) #Installed FC-Heatexchanger capacity [kWh]
    @variable(m, cap_cycle >= 0) #Installed Hydrogen-tank capacity [kWh] 

    @variable(m, R_EL[1:P] >= 0) #electrical power consumed by the Electrolyzer in period p [kWh]
    @variable(m, R_SOFC[1:P] >= 0) #hydrogen consumed by the Fuell Cell in period p [kWh]
    @variable(m, EL_Output[1:P] >= 0) #hydrogen offered by the Electrolyzer in period p [kWh] 
    @variable(m, SOFC_Output[1:P] >= 0) #electrical power offered by Fuell Cell in period p [kWh]
    @variable(m, SOC_H2T[1:P] >= 0) #State of charge of the hydrogen tank in period p [kWh]
    @variable(m, R_cycle[1:P] >= 0) #thermal power consumed by the ORC in period p [kWh]
    @variable(m, cycle_Output[1:P] >= 0) #electrical power offered by the ORC in period p [kWh]

    @variable(m, heat_EL[1:P] >= 0) #heat produced in period p [kWh_therm] produced by Electrolyzer
    @variable(m, heat_SOFC[1:P] >= 0) #heat produced in period p [kWh_therm] produced by Fuell Cell
   
    @variable(m, heat_diff[1:P] >=0 ) #heat that isnt covered by heat_EL and heat_FC per period in kWh

    #CAPEX
    @variable(m , CAPEX_PV >= 0) #Capital Expenditure of PV [€/kW]
    @variable(m , CAPEX_Wind >= 0) #Capital Expenditure of Wind [€/kW]
    @variable(m , CAPEX_EL >= 0) #Capital Expenditure of Electrolyzer [€/kW]
    @variable(m , CAPEX_SOFC >= 0) #Capital Expenditure of Fuell Cell [€/kW]
    @variable(m , CAPEX_H2T >= 0) #Capital Expenditure of hydrogen tank [€/kW]
    @variable(m , CAPEX_Heatex_EL >= 0) #Capital Expenditure of Electrolyzer-Heatexchanger [€/kW]
    @variable(m , CAPEX_Heatex_SOFC >= 0) #Capital Expenditure of FuellCell-Heatexchanger [€/kW]
    @variable(m , CAPEX_cycle >=0) #Capital Expenditure of ORC [€/kW]
    @variable(m , CAPEX_total >= 0) #Capital Expenditure of all OPEX combined [€/kW]

    #OPEX
    @variable(m , OPEX_PV >= 0) #Operational Expenditure of PV [€/a]
    @variable(m , OPEX_Wind >= 0) #Operational Expenditure of Wind [€/a]    
    @variable(m , OPEX_EL >= 0) #Operational Expenditure of Electrolyzer [€/a]
    @variable(m , OPEX_SOFC >= 0) #Operational Expenditure of Fuell Cell [€/a]
    @variable(m , OPEX_H2T >= 0) #Operational Expenditure of hydrogen tank [€/a]
    @variable(m , OPEX_Heatex_EL >= 0) #Operational Expenditure of Electrolyzer-Heatexchanger [€/a]
    @variable(m , OPEX_Heatex_SOFC >= 0) #Operational Expenditure of FuellCell-Heatexchanger [€/a]
    @variable(m , OPEX_total >= 0) #Operational Expenditure of all OPEX combined [€/a]
    @variable(m , OPEX_cycle >= 0) #Operational Expenditure of battery [€/a]

    #Finanzkennzahlen
    @variable(m, Investment_Cost)
    @variable(m, NPV_annual_costs)
    @variable(m, annual_cost)
    @variable(m, Restwert)    
    
    #OBJECTIVE Function
    @objective(m , Min, EC)

    #Constraints
    #Max-Values
    @constraint(m, cap_PV <= 2100 ) #da verfügbare PV-Fläche = 10.000 m^2 und bei nominellem Wirkungsgrad von 0,21
    @constraint(m, cap_Wind <= 1500) #da verfügbare Fläche bei 75.000 m^2 und nominellem Wirkungsgrad von 0,02
    @constraint(m, cap_EL <= 100000 * EL_bin) #Entscheidet ob cap_EL 0 ist oder Obergrenze bekommt
    @constraint(m, cap_EL >= EL_bin) #Falls cap_EL eine Obergrenze bekommt hat es den Minimalwert 1. Somit wird vermieden, dass die Binärvariable = 1 ist, aber dennoch kein Elektrolyseur gekauft wird
    @constraint(m, cap_H2T <= 100000 * EL_bin) #wird entweder 0 oder 100000, abhängig davon ob EL_bin existiert
    @constraint(m, cap_H2T >= EL_bin)
    @constraint(m, cap_SOFC <= 100000 * EL_bin)
    @constraint(m, cap_SOFC >= EL_bin)
    @constraint(m, cap_Heatex_EL <= 100000 * EL_bin)
    @constraint(m, cap_Heatex_SOFC <= 100000 * EL_bin)
    @constraint(m, cap_cycle <= 100000 * EL_bin )
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], E_sold[p] <= 100000)
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], E_purchased[p] <= 100000)
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], E_sold[p] <= generation_pv[p] * cap_PV + generation_wind[p] * cap_Wind + SOFC_Output[p] + cycle_Output[p])
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], H_purchased[p] <= 100000)

    
    # (1) Maximaler Einkaufswert an Energie - benötigt für Leistungspreiskomponente
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], max_E_purchased >= E_purchased[p])

    # (2) - (6) Totals - Summen der Nachfrage, Erzeugungsleistungen, Stromhandel
    @constraint(m, Total_Demand == sum( u[p] for p=1:P))
    @constraint(m, Total_H_Demand == sum( t[p] for p=1:P))
    @constraint(m, Total_PV_gen == sum( generation_pv[p] for p=1:P) * cap_PV)
    @constraint(m, Total_Wind_gen == sum( generation_wind[p] for p=1:P) * cap_Wind)
    @constraint(m, Total_H_buy == sum(H_purchased[p] for p=1:P))
    @constraint(m, Total_buy == sum( E_purchased[p] for p=1:P))
    @constraint(m, Total_sell == sum( E_sold[p] for p=1:P))
    @constraint(m, Total_heat_gen == sum( heat_EL[p] + heat_SOFC[p] for p=1:P))
    @constraint(m, Total_cycle_gen == sum(cycle_Output[p] for p=1:P))
    @constraint(m, Total_FC_gen == sum(SOFC_Output[p] for p=1:P))
    @constraint(m, Total_H2_gen == sum(EL_Output[p] for p=1:P))

    # (7) - (14) CAPEX - Berechnung der anfallenden Investitionskosten für alle im Szenario betrachteten Anlagen
    @constraint(m, CAPEX_PV == Capex_PV * cap_PV )           
    @constraint(m, CAPEX_Wind == Capex_Wind * cap_Wind )
    @constraint(m, CAPEX_EL == Capex_EL * cap_EL )
    @constraint(m, CAPEX_SOFC == Capex_SOFC * cap_SOFC)
    @constraint(m, CAPEX_H2T == Capex_H2T * cap_H2T )
    @constraint(m, CAPEX_Heatex_EL == Capex_Heatex * cap_Heatex_EL )
    @constraint(m, CAPEX_Heatex_SOFC == Capex_Heatex * cap_Heatex_SOFC )
    @constraint(m, CAPEX_cycle == Capex_cycle * cap_cycle )
  
    # (15) - (23) OPEX - Berechnung der laufenden Anlagenkosten für den Betrachtungszeitraum (20 Jahre)
    @constraint(m, OPEX_PV == cap_PV * Opex_PV )
    @constraint(m, OPEX_Wind == (cap_Wind * Opex_Wind + Opex_Wind_var * Total_Wind_gen) )
    @constraint(m, OPEX_EL == Opex_EL * CAPEX_EL )
    @constraint(m, OPEX_SOFC == Opex_SOFC * CAPEX_SOFC)
    @constraint(m, OPEX_H2T == Opex_H2T * CAPEX_H2T )
    @constraint(m, OPEX_Heatex_EL == Opex_Heatex * cap_Heatex_EL + Opex_Heatex_var * sum(heat_EL[p] for p=1:P))
    @constraint(m, OPEX_Heatex_SOFC == Opex_Heatex * cap_Heatex_SOFC + Opex_Heatex_var * sum(heat_SOFC[p] for p=1:P))
    @constraint(m, OPEX_cycle == Opex_cycle * CAPEX_cycle)
    @constraint(m, OPEX_total == OPEX_PV + OPEX_Wind + OPEX_H2T + OPEX_EL + OPEX_SOFC + OPEX_Heatex_EL + OPEX_Heatex_SOFC + OPEX_cycle)

    # (33) - (38) Elektrolyseur und Brennstoffzelle - Outputbeschränkungen und -berechnungen
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], EL_Output[p] <= cap_EL )
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], EL_Output[p] == R_EL[p] * Phi_EL)
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], SOFC_Output[p] <= cap_SOFC)
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], SOFC_Output[p] == R_SOFC[p] * Phi_SOFC)
    
    # (39) - (43) Wasserstofftank - SOC-Berechnung
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], SOC_H2T[p] >= SOC_H2T_MIN * cap_H2T )
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], SOC_H2T[p] <= SOC_H2T_MAX * cap_H2T )
    @constraint(m, [p=1], SOC_H2T[p] == SOC_H2T_INIT * cap_H2T + EL_Output[p] - R_SOFC[p])
    @constraint(m, [p=2:P], SOC_H2T[p] == SOC_H2T[p-1] + EL_Output[p] - R_SOFC[p])
    @constraint(m, [p=P], SOC_H2T[p] == SOC_H2T_INIT * cap_H2T)

    # (44) - (47) Wärmeplattentauscher - Outputbeschränkung und Berechnungen
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], heat_EL[p] == R_EL[p] * Phi_EL_heat * Phi_Heatex )
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], heat_EL[p] <= cap_Heatex_EL )
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], heat_SOFC[p] == R_SOFC[p] * Phi_SOFC_heat * Phi_Heatex)
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], heat_SOFC[p] <= cap_Heatex_SOFC ) 
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], heat_diff[p] == t[p] - (heat_EL[p] + heat_SOFC[p])) 

    #() - () ORC 
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], cycle_Output[p] <= R_cycle[p] * Phi_cycle)  
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], cycle_Output[p] <= cap_cycle)
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], R_cycle[p] <= (heat_EL[p] + heat_SOFC[p]) - t[p])
    #@constraint(m, [p=1:P], cycle_Output[p] <= R_cycle[p])
    
    # (48) - (49) Energiebilanzen
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], u[p] + E_sold[p] + R_EL[p]  <= E_purchased[p] + generation_pv[p] * cap_PV + generation_wind[p] * cap_Wind + SOFC_Output[p] + cycle_Output[p])
    @constraint(m, [p=1:P], H_purchased[p] + heat_EL[p] + heat_SOFC[p]   >= t[p] + R_cycle[p])

    #(49) - (51) Kostenrechnung
    @constraint(m, Investment_Cost == CAPEX_PV + CAPEX_Wind + CAPEX_H2T + CAPEX_EL * Reinv_EL_faktor + CAPEX_SOFC * Reinv_SOFC_faktor + CAPEX_Heatex_EL + CAPEX_Heatex_SOFC + CAPEX_cycle)
    @constraint(m, Restwert == Restwert_PV_faktor * CAPEX_PV + Restwert_Wind_faktor * CAPEX_Wind + Restwert_EL_faktor * CAPEX_EL + Restwert_SOFC_faktor * CAPEX_SOFC + Restwert_H2T_faktor * CAPEX_H2T + Restwert_Heatex_faktor * CAPEX_Heatex_EL + Restwert_Heatex_faktor * CAPEX_Heatex_SOFC)
    @constraint(m, annual_cost == OPEX_total + sum(E_purchased[p] * energy_price_buy[p] for p=1:P) + max_E_purchased * Netzentgelt_LP - sum(E_sold[p] * Stromverkaufspreis[p] for p=1:P) + Total_H_buy * FWP )

    @constraint(m, NPV_annual_costs == sum((annual_cost*((1+inflation)^t)/((1+WACC)^t)) for t=1:20))

    # (52) Energiekosten
    @constraint(m, EC >= (NPV_annual_costs + Investment_Cost - Restwert) * CRF )

    #OPTIMIZE
    
    optimize!(m);
    
    #RETURN
    #Variable RETURN
    EC = JuMP.value.(EC);
    Total_Demand = JuMP.value.(Total_Demand);
    Total_PV_gen = JuMP.value.(Total_PV_gen);
    Total_Wind_gen = JuMP.value.(Total_Wind_gen);
    Total_FC_gen = JuMP.value.(Total_FC_gen);
    Total_H2_gen = JuMP.value.(Total_H2_gen);
    Total_buy = JuMP.value.(Total_buy);
    Total_sell = JuMP.value.(Total_sell);
    Total_heat_gen = JuMP.value.(Total_heat_gen);
    Total_cycle_gen = JuMP.value.(Total_cycle_gen);
    Total_H_Demand = JuMP.value.(Total_H_Demand);
    E_purchased = JuMP.value.(E_purchased);
    E_sold = JuMP.value.(E_sold);
    H_purchased = JuMP.value.(H_purchased);
    heat_diff = JuMP.value.(heat_diff);
    max_E_purchased = JuMP.value.(max_E_purchased);
    u = JuMP.value.(u)

    cap_PV = JuMP.value.(cap_PV);
    cap_Wind = JuMP.value.(cap_Wind);
    cap_EL = JuMP.value.(cap_EL);
    cap_SOFC = JuMP.value.(cap_SOFC);
    cap_H2T = JuMP.value.(cap_H2T);
    cap_Heatex_EL = JuMP.value.(cap_Heatex_EL);
    cap_Heatex_SOFC = JuMP.value.(cap_Heatex_SOFC);
    cap_cycle = JuMP.value.(cap_cycle);

    OPEX_PV = JuMP.value.(OPEX_PV);
    OPEX_Wind = JuMP.value.(OPEX_Wind);
    OPEX_EL = JuMP.value.(OPEX_EL);
    OPEX_SOFC = JuMP.value.(OPEX_SOFC);
    OPEX_H2T = JuMP.value.(OPEX_H2T);
    OPEX_Heatex_EL = JuMP.value.(OPEX_Heatex_EL);
    OPEX_Heatex_SOFC = JuMP.value.(OPEX_Heatex_SOFC);
    OPEX_total = JuMP.value.(OPEX_total);
    OPEX_cycle = JuMP.value.(OPEX_cycle);

    R_EL = JuMP.value.(R_EL);
    R_SOFC = JuMP.value.(R_SOFC);
    EL_Output = JuMP.value.(EL_Output);
    SOFC_Output = JuMP.value.(SOFC_Output);
    SOC_H2T = JuMP.value.(SOC_H2T);

    heat_EL = JuMP.value.(heat_EL);
    heat_SOFC = JuMP.value.(heat_SOFC);

    cycle_Output = JuMP.value.(cycle_Output);
    R_cycle = JuMP.value.(R_cycle)

    CAPEX_PV = JuMP.value.(CAPEX_PV);
    CAPEX_Wind = JuMP.value.(CAPEX_Wind);
    CAPEX_EL = JuMP.value.(CAPEX_EL);
    CAPEX_SOFC = JuMP.value.(CAPEX_SOFC);
    CAPEX_Heatex_EL = JuMP.value.(CAPEX_Heatex_EL);
    CAPEX_Heatex_SOFC = JuMP.value.(CAPEX_Heatex_SOFC);
    CAPEX_H2T = JuMP.value.(CAPEX_H2T);
    CAPEX_cycle = JuMP.value.(CAPEX_cycle);
    CAPEX_total = JuMP.value.(CAPEX_total);

    Investment_Cost = JuMP.value.(Investment_Cost);
    NPV_annual_costs = JuMP.value.(NPV_annual_costs);
    annual_cost = JuMP.value.(annual_cost);
    Restwert = JuMP.value.(Restwert);

    returned_values = Dict(
        "Totals" => Dict(
            :EC => round.(JuMP.value.(EC), digits=4),
            :Total_Demand => round.(JuMP.value.(Total_Demand), digits=4),
            :Total_H_Demand => round.(JuMP.value.(Total_H_Demand), digits=4),
            :Total_PV_gen => round.(JuMP.value.(Total_PV_gen), digits=4),
            :Total_Wind_gen => round.(JuMP.value.(Total_Wind_gen), digits=4),
            :Total_FC_gen => round.(JuMP.value.(Total_FC_gen), digits=4),
            :Total_heat_gen => round.(JuMP.value.(Total_heat_gen), digits=4),
            :Total_cycle_gen => round.(JuMP.value.(Total_cycle_gen), digits=4),
            :Total_H2_gen => round.(JuMP.value.(Total_H2_gen), digits=4),
            :Total_buy => round.(JuMP.value.(Total_buy), digits=4),
            :Total_H_buy => round.(JuMP.value.(Total_H_buy), digits=4),
            :Total_sell => round.(JuMP.value.(Total_sell), digits=4),
            :CAPEX_total => round.(JuMP.value.(CAPEX_total), digits=4),
            :OPEX_total => round.(JuMP.value.(OPEX_total), digits=4)
            ),
        "Purchases" => Dict(
            :E_purchased => round.(JuMP.value.(E_purchased), digits=4),
            :E_sold => round.(JuMP.value.(E_sold), digits=4),
            :max_E_purchased => round.(JuMP.value.(max_E_purchased), digits=4),
            :H_purchased => round.(JuMP.value.(H_purchased), digits = 4)
            ),
        "Capacities" => Dict(
            :cap_PV => round.(JuMP.value.(cap_PV), digits=4),
            :cap_Wind => round.(JuMP.value.(cap_Wind), digits=4),
            :cap_EL => round.(JuMP.value.(cap_EL), digits=4),
            :cap_SOFC => round.(JuMP.value.(cap_SOFC), digits=4),
            :cap_H2T => round.(JuMP.value.(cap_H2T), digits=4),
            :cap_Heatex_EL => round.(JuMP.value.(cap_Heatex_EL), digits=4),
            :cap_Heatex_SOFC => round.(JuMP.value.(cap_Heatex_SOFC), digits=4),
            :cap_cycle => round.(JuMP.value.(cap_cycle), digits=4),
            ),
        "CAPEX" => Dict(
            :CAPEX_PV => round.(JuMP.value.(CAPEX_PV), digits=4),
            :CAPEX_Wind => round.(JuMP.value.(CAPEX_Wind), digits=4),
            :CAPEX_EL => round.(JuMP.value.(CAPEX_EL), digits=4),
            :CAPEX_SOFC => round.(JuMP.value.(CAPEX_SOFC), digits=4),
            :CAPEX_Heatex_EL => round.(JuMP.value.(CAPEX_Heatex_EL), digits=4),
            :CAPEX_Heatex_SOFC => round.(JuMP.value.(CAPEX_Heatex_SOFC), digits=4),
            :CAPEX_H2T => round.(JuMP.value.(CAPEX_H2T), digits=4),
            :CAPEX_cycle => round.(JuMP.value.(CAPEX_cycle), digits=4),
            ),
        "OPEX" => Dict(
            :OPEX_PV => round.(JuMP.value.(OPEX_PV), digits=4),
            :OPEX_Wind => round.(JuMP.value.(OPEX_Wind), digits=4),
            :OPEX_EL => round.(JuMP.value.(OPEX_EL), digits=4),
            :OPEX_SOFC => round.(JuMP.value.(OPEX_SOFC), digits=4),
            :OPEX_H2T => round.(JuMP.value.(OPEX_H2T), digits=4),
            :OPEX_Heatex_EL => round.(JuMP.value.(OPEX_Heatex_EL), digits=4),
            :OPEX_Heatex_SOFC => round.(JuMP.value.(OPEX_Heatex_SOFC), digits=4),
            :OPEX_cycle => round.(JuMP.value.(OPEX_cycle), digits=4),
            ),
        "SOC Storages" => Dict(
            :SOC_H2T => round.(JuMP.value.(SOC_H2T), digits=4),
            :R_SOFC => round.(JuMP.value.(R_SOFC), digits=4),
            :EL_Output => round.(JuMP.value.(EL_Output), digits=4)
            ),
        "EL und FC Flows + Cycle" => Dict(
            :R_EL => round.(JuMP.value.(R_EL), digits=4),
            :R_SOFC => round.(JuMP.value.(R_SOFC), digits=4),
            :EL_Output => round.(JuMP.value.(EL_Output), digits=4),
            :SOFC_Output => round.(JuMP.value.(SOFC_Output), digits=4),
            :heat_EL => round.(JuMP.value.(heat_EL), digits=4),
            :heat_SOFC => round.(JuMP.value.(heat_SOFC), digits=4),
            :cycle_Output => round.(JuMP.value.(cycle_Output), digits =4),
            :heat_diff => round.(JuMP.value.(heat_diff), digits = 4),
            :R_cycle => round.(JuMP.value.(R_cycle), digits = 4)
            ),
        "Finanzkennzahlen" => Dict(
            :Investment_Cost => round.(JuMP.value.(Investment_Cost), digits=4),
            :NPV_annual_costs => round.(JuMP.value.(NPV_annual_costs), digits=4),
            :annual_cost => round.(JuMP.value.(annual_cost), digits=4),
            :Restwert => round.(JuMP.value.(Restwert), digits=4)
        ), 
        "Lastprofil" => Dict(
            :u => round.(JuMP.value.(u), digits=4),
            :t => round.(JuMP.value.(t), digits =4)
            )
        )
        
    return returned_values
end


Welcome to OR.SE. It would be great to write the math model beside the provided code.

What exactly does that mean? i could send you the formulation for the model-description i used in my thesis, but it's all in german. Or do u want me to copy out 50 formulas? i can do it, but i guess they give the same information as the provided code

Try making use of the IIS feature of commercial solvers (as you tagged gurobi), e.g. by forcing any heat-purchase variable to some positive value (any variable where it makes sense: guaranteed to be a partial-solution to some full-solution), run it: according to your description you expect (false) infeasibility, then run IIS analysis on the same model (incl. the fixed-var) to get some smaller conflict-set to look at. | Apart from that there is also the general recommendation: remove / relax your constraints interactively until things change to "bisect" potential sources of infeasibility.

i dont know anything about partial solutions/full solutions/ IIS and what not. it's my second model i ever write. What are these things and how do i do that?

The thing with commercial solvers: they usually have good documentation. Read them! As you are using a third-party pool howewer for modelling you will need to check yourself how JuMP is wrapping IIS. But that's only one more google search away.
